# How can I query for required fields in a Drupal 7 Database?

Tags: drupal

I am trying to write a function that will get me the names of the required fields from the drupal database.  Then, so I can write one validation function for alerting the user that he/she has not entered in a required field.

Comment: The required fields for what?

Comment: I need to know the required fields for a specific content type so that I can write one validation function instead of one for each required field.  I am trying to migrate content from another CMS to Drupal using node_save() but it skips the drupal validations.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this quite easily using the [`field_info_instances()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.info.inc/function/field_info_instances/7) function:

```
$instances = field_info_instances('node', 'invoice');
$required = array();
foreach ($instances as $field_name => $instance) {
  if ($instance['required'] == 1) {
    $required[] = $field_name;
  }
}
```

To get the field type you need to query for the field not the instance. In the loop you can call:

```
$field = field_info_field($field_name);
$type = $field['type'];
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the field type too?